# How obtain audio metadata when it's playing?

Tags: java, concurrency, javafx

Im creating a simple audio player. The listener events are fine, except MapChangeListener. When run the App, the listener for MapChangeListener (metadata) are fired all at the same time and get the last metadata track.

For example:

- The tracklist has 11 tracks.
- Run my App
- MapChangeListener is fired for all tracks.
- The metadata showed in my App is the last track.

This i wanna do:

- Run the App
- MapChangeListener should be fired for the current track only.
- Next Track -> MapChangeListener for it.

I've read that `getMetadata()` method of Media is executed in the same thread of the App, and for this reason i can't add the Listener to the metadata in **setOnPlaying( Runnable() )** method.

Also tried with **Platform.runLater()** inside the Playing event, but simple doesn't Works.

I appreciated any help. Thanks.

**My Listener**

```
final public class MetadataListener implements MapChangeListener<String, Object> {

    private PlayerControl gui;
    private static int count;

    public MetadataListener(PlayerControl gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }
    @Override
    public void onChanged(Change<? extends String, ? extends Object> change) {
        count++;
        if(change.wasAdded()) {
            handleMetadata(change.getKey().toString(), change.getValueAdded());
        }
    }



    private void handleMetadata(String key, Object value) {
            if(key.equals("title"))
                gui.getLblTitle().setText(value.toString());
            if(key.equals("artist"))
                gui.getLblArtist().setText(value.toString());
            if(key.equals("album"))
                gui.getLblAlbum().setText(value.toString());
            if(key.equals("year"))
                gui.getLblYear().setText(value.toString());
            if(key.equals("image"))
                gui.getImgViewAlbum().setImage((Image) value);
        }

    }
```

**My Player**

```
public void createMediaList() {
        for(String file : filterFiles()) {
            playList.add(createPlayer(file));
        }
        if(playList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No se han encontrado archivos multimedia");
            Platform.exit();
            return;
        }
    }

private MediaPlayer createPlayer(String filePath) {
        Media media = new Media(new File(dir.toString()+"/"+filePath).toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        this.attachListeners(player);
        return player;
    }



private void attachListeners(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.setOnPlaying(() -> {
            duration = player.getMedia().getDuration();
            gui.getLblTotalDuration().setText(formatCurrentDuration(duration));
            gui.getBtnPlayPause().setText(" | | ");
            updateValues();
        });
        player.currentTimeProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            updateValues();
        });
        player.getMedia().getMetadata().addListener(metadataListener);
        player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
            player.stop();
            this.nextMedia();
        });
        //player.setOnStopped( () -> player.getMedia().getMetadata().removeListener(metadataListener));
        player.setOnPaused( () -> gui.getBtnPlayPause().setText("►"));
        player.setOnError(() -> System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error"));
    }

protected void updateValues() {
        Label lblCurrentTime = gui.getLblCurrentTime();
        Label lblTotalDuration = gui.getLblTotalDuration();
        Slider sldPlayer = gui.getSldPlayer();
        //Slider sldVolume = gui.getSldVolume();

        if(lblCurrentTime != null && lblTotalDuration != null && sldPlayer != null && /*sldVolume != null &&*/ duration != null) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                Duration currentTime = this.playList.get(currentMediaIndex).getCurrentTime();
                lblCurrentTime.setText(formatCurrentDuration(currentTime));
                sldPlayer.setDisable(duration.isUnknown());
                if(!sldPlayer.isDisabled() && duration.greaterThan(Duration.ZERO) && !sldPlayer.isValueChanging()) {
                    sldPlayer.setValue(currentTime.divide(duration).toMillis() * 100.0);
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for

> MapChangeListener is fired for all tracks
>
> The metadata showed in my App is the last track.

is in your code:

```
for(String file : filterFiles()) {
    playList.add(createPlayer(file));
}

private MediaPlayer createPlayer(String filePath) {
    Media media = new Media(new File(dir.toString()+"/"+filePath).toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    this.attachListeners(player);
    return player;
}
```

When you launch your application, you are creating the media player for all the tracks on the playlist and attaching a listener to them. All the listeners are fired once the metadata is retrived for each track, all the labels are updated and that's why you only see the last track metadata.

So first, retrieve the list of valid media players, and call the first track:

```
private final List<MediaPlayer> playList = new ArrayList<>();

public void createMediaList() {
    for(String file : filterFiles()) {
        MediaPlayer player=createPlayer(file);
        if(player!=null){
            playList.add(player);
        }
    }
    if(playList.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No se han encontrado archivos multimedia");
        Platform.exit();
        return;
    }
    // start first track
    nextMedia();
}
```

where

```
private MediaPlayer createPlayer(String filePath) {
    try{
        Media media = new Media(new File(dir+"/"+filePath).toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer player=new MediaPlayer(media);
        return player;
    } catch(MediaException me){
        System.out.println("MediaException "+me);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Since not every file could be valid, it's convenient to surround the mediaplayer creation in a try catch.

Now, `nextMedia()` just retrieves the media player of one single track, and attaches the listeners.

*EDIT:* Usually, when the media player is created, is convenient the use of `setOnReady()` to start playing, but in this case the media players for all the tracks are created at the beginning, and the players are ready at this point.

```
private void nextMedia(){
    MediaPlayer player=playList.get(currentMediaIndex++);
    attachListeners(player);
    if(player!=null){
        player.play();
    } else {
        nextMedia();
    }
}
```

When the track is ready all the metadata will be retrieved and the labels updated:

```
private void attachListeners(MediaPlayer player) {
    ...
    player.getMedia().getMetadata().addListener(metadataListener);
    ...
    player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
        player.getMedia().getMetadata().removeListener(metadataListener);
        player.stop();
        nextMedia();
    });
}
```

And when the track ends, your listener will call again `nextMedia()`.

Comment: Excelent response, now it's Works like a charm!. Thank you very much man. Muchas gracias! Todo funciónó correctamente :)

Comment: forgive me for ask but, i modify a Little the code and every metadata sets but the image doesn't show correctly. Two first songs has not image, and third+ have the same image.

I've put the App in my github. Please, can you check it?

Thanks. Muchas gracias profe :)

Puede darme su Skype?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a slight modification: removed `player.setOnReady()`, since the players are created at the beginning, and their status is Ready. Also, is advisable to remove the listener. Regarding the images, could you print to console the value of the tracks' images, to check if they are different?

Comment: Thank you very much. The álbum image problema looks like a bug of JavaFX. `key.equals("image")` only detects one image in the 11 tracks. But, with Media Player of Windows, all images display correctly. ¿It's a bug?

Thank you very much.

Comment: But are the images different for each track? Notice you have a listerner for changes, if the image is the same, there won't be a `change.wasAdded()`, and you will see always the first image.

Comment: Yes. Whe i see the tracks with Windows Media Player, i can see the images (i dont know if this application search online and set data in the .mp3 file). I'll try to extrack the track's metadata with a tool for see if these contain images. I'll update in a few minuts. Gracias por su interés profe.

Comment: Yes, 8 of 11 tracks has a image in metadata. But the listener only catch one. I've verify that every track has attached correctly the MapChangeListener, put and System.out.println in `handleMetadata` method and all tracks print text.

I don't understand why don't display the images. All the code is now in my github. Please, if i'm doing something wrong tell me and explain me why. Thank you very much :)

https://github.com/GusGarsaky/FXPLayer (updated)

Comment: Edit. The tracks doesn't have metadata (already im watching this with EasyTag) but Windows shows images for some .mp3 files. Im adding manually albums arts to the tracks and every is working good now.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Edito: Parece que las pistas no tenían album arts. Es raro, no tengo idea de porqué Windows muestra imágenes de algunos archivos .mp3 cuando el programa EasyTag me dice que no.

Estoy agregando manualmente los album art a las pistas y todo parece que está funcionando correctamente.

Un saludo y gracias por su ayuda, profesor.